# Backbone's fetch(): Add only models that are new to the collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

When a `fetch` is called (in response to a user's action) after an initial `fetch`, many of the newly fetched models can be similar to the existing models from the initial `fetch`. If I call `fetch` with the `add: true` option, there can be duplicate models in the collection.

**Problem:** Instead of removing all existing models (say with `id=1,2,3,4`) from the collection and inserting the newly fetched models (`id=1,2,3,5`), is it possible to do the following 2 operations:

1. Add only the new models `id=5`, resulting in a collection with `id=1,2,3,4,5`. Then render only the new Views (`id=5`)
2. Add the new models `id=5` and remove the models not found in the new `fetch` (`id=4`). Then render the new Views (`id=5`) and remove the old Views (`id=4`)

**Attempt:**

Instead of calling `App.listingCollection.fetch()`, the `fetchNew()` function is used. This works to only add the new models `id=5` to the collection.

How should the rendering of the new views only (`id=5`) be triggered without re-rendering the existing views `id=1,2,3,4`? I tried this with the line `new ListingMarkerView({ model:item }).render();` within `ListingCollection`, but I get an error responding to the line `var marker = L.marker([this.model.get('lat'), this.model.get('lng')]);` in `ListingMarkerView` :

**Error**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'get'
```

**Collection**

```
ListingCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Listing,
    url: '/api/search_by_bounds',

    fetchNew: function(options) {
        options = options || {};
        var collection = this,
            success = options.success;
        options.success = function(resp, status, xhr) {
            _(collection.parse(resp, xhr)).each(function(item) {
                // added this conditional block
                if (!collection.get(item.id)) {
                    collection.add(item, {silent:true});
                    new ListingMarkerView({ model:item }).render();
                }
            });
            if (!options.silent) {
                collection.trigger('reset', collection, options);
            }
            if (success) success(collection, resp);
        };
        return (this.sync || Backbone.sync).call(this, 'read', this, options);
    }
});
```

**View**

```
ListingMarkerView = Backbone.View.extend({

    render: function() {
        var marker = L.marker([this.model.get('lat'), this.model.get('lng')]);
        markers.addLayer(marker);
    },

    close: function() {
        this.unbind;
    }

});
```

Comment: Does the ``update: true`` do what you want? ```
App.listingCollection.fetch({update: true});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A restful API has no concept of state of the clients it's speaking to, therefore when making a `GET` request to retrieve a list of objects (e.g. http://example.com/restapi/user/), the rest server should ALWAYS return a full list of the matching objects.

On the Backbone end, you should then just `.reset` your collection with the list from the server.  `.reset` will empty the collection and then add all the items, like:

```
my_collection.fetch({success: function(collection, resp){ 
    collection.reset(resp, {silent: true});
}});
```

This way you don't get collisions and you don't have to worry about anything.  Except if you've got models you've changed in the collection locally that haven't been saved back to the server.

If you're looking for a way to prevent modification of local items within a collection, that will need something like the sorcery you're speaking of above.